# How to set waypoints on google map according to basis of latitude and longitude?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-waypoints

In this article, they set waypoints according to location, But I want to set waypoints according to latitude and longitude. Is it possible, if yes please guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. You should follow Google Maps JavaScript API reference documentation.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsWaypoint

As you can see the location property can be string or LatLng or Place object.

So, in your code you can write something like

```
waypts.push({
    location: new google.maps.LatLng(myLat,myLng),
    stopover: true
});
```